# How to Rank using Rank formula basis different criteria in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have below table

```
Month   LoB Score   Rank
Jan     A   1   
Jan     B   2   
Feb     B   1   
Feb     B   2   
Jan     A   2   
Mar     C   1   
Feb     A   3   
Jan     A   3   
Mar     C   2   
Mar     A   1   
Mar     C   3
```

I want to Rank the scores basis Month and LoB. For ex in Jan for A whatever is highest will get Rank 1. Similarly in Jan for LoB B whatever is highest will get Rank 1.
I understand that Index and Row formula are to be used in conjunction with Rank.eq but i am unable to put it together at all. I would appreciate any help on this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Row1 is the header row and actual data lies in the range A2:C11, then try this...

In D2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$11=A2)*($B$2:$B$11=B2)*($C$2:$C$11>C2))+1
```

and copy it down.
[image]

Comment: I totally was going down the wrong path. Didn't catch he was looking for a rank just within each Month/LoB. Nice.

Comment: @sktneer, Absolutely working. Thank you pal for this. This brings me to efficiency question. I am going to apply this to 4 x 20K Plus records. Is it going to slow it down? is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Don't think so. It should work for that number of rows.

Comment: For large ranges `COUNTIFS` will be faster than `SUMPRODUCT`, translates to `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,B2,$C$2:$C$11,">"&C2)+1`

Answer (score 0):

AoA / Good morning 
by using Rank formula problems face in correct position.=RANK(K5,K5:K34)

```
Marks     Position    total marks 350
obtained
    290     29
    346     9 (student obtained 346 marks how he have 9th position he must be 4th position)
    250     30
    343     20
    345         13
    342     21
    334     26
    346     9
    345     13
    346     9
    346     9
    348     5
    350     1
    349     3
    335     24
    345     13
    335     24
    348     5
    339     22
    295     28
    350     1
    345     13
    348     5
    344     18
    345     13
    338     23
    347     2
    349     3
    297     27
```